Can you add interactive effects between Principal Components (PCs) and other predictors in linear models?
I am building a glmm where I have 3 PCs (principal components) as predictors in the model. These PCs are based on soil variables (pH, CEC, nutrients) so I have reason to believe they may interact with other environmental predictors in the model (i.e. soil moisture, canopy gap index). Would the following be valid:
$$
y = x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}PC_{1} + x_{4}PC_{2} + \epsilon
$$
whereby, $x_{3}$ and $x_{4}$ are soil moisture and canopy gap index and they are interacting with the principal components.

What is your hesitation about its legitimacy?

Are any of your proposed interacting predictors also contributing to the PCs? (E.g., is soil moisture included in the PC calculations on "soil variables"?)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the principal component analysis is based only on 3 variables (pH, CEC, nutrients) and you are using 2 PCs afterwards, I don't see the point of using a PCA in the first place. However, you need to explain the problem more precisely.
